# Setting custom library path for python packages

Tags: python, pip

How can I tell python to look for libraries other than the default one which is used by pip? The error is

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

and libraries are here:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch/torch/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch/torch/lib
$ ls -l /mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch/torch/lib
total 555032
drwxr-xr-x 5 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 12  2019 c10d
drwxr-xr-x 4 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 24  2019 cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    494106 Dec 24  2019 libasmjit.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    240624 Dec 24  2019 libc10_cuda.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   2113386 Dec 24  2019 libc10d.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    376256 Dec 24  2019 libc10.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   1602816 Dec 24  2019 libcaffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    125024 Dec 24  2019 libcaffe2_module_test_dynamic.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group     13304 Dec 24  2019 libcaffe2_nvrtc.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    163968 Dec 24  2019 libcaffe2_observers.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group      7250 Dec 24  2019 libclog.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group     96062 Dec 24  2019 libcpuinfo.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group  13214612 Dec 24  2019 libfbgemm.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   1363714 Dec 24  2019 libgloo.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   8854326 Dec 24  2019 libgloo_cuda.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group  51989326 Dec 24  2019 libmkldnn.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    255332 Dec 24  2019 libnnpack.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   6090766 Dec 24  2019 libprotobuf.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    779994 Dec 24  2019 libprotobuf-lite.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   5386362 Dec 24  2019 libprotoc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group     11302 Dec 24  2019 libpthreadpool.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    190858 Dec 24  2019 libpytorch_qnnpack.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group    159656 Dec 24  2019 libqnnpack.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 12  2019 libshm
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group     51608 Dec 24  2019 libshm.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 12  2019 libshm_windows
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group   4425114 Dec 24  2019 libsleef.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group 111076296 Dec 24  2019 libtorch_cpu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group 323114952 Dec 24  2019 libtorch_cuda.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group  36070912 Dec 24  2019 libtorch_python.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mahmood mahmood-group      7488 Dec 24  2019 libtorch.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 24  2019 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x 3 mahmood mahmood-group      4096 Dec 24  2019 python2.7
```

Comment: have you tried appending to sys.path?

Comment: @L.Grozinger: How exactly? In main.py ?

Comment: yes exactly, something like `import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/lib')` ?

Comment: I got the same error. The first three lines are `from __future__ import print_function` and `import sys` and `sys.path.append('/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch/torch/lib')`

Comment: hm. I'm not a pytorch user, but that path looks wrong to me. Have you tried instead `'/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch'` , or even `'/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch/torch'`? It would depend on the directory structure of the pytorch project.

Comment: Yes thank you. `/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch` works.

Comment: By the way, are you still using Python 2.x? I ***highly*** recommend updating to Python 3.x, since has Python 2 is already past its end of life for a while.

Comment: @wovano just curious, what makes you think the OP is using Python2.x?

Comment: @L.Grozinger, the `ImportError`, which is now called `ModuleNotFoundError`. But on second thought, this seems to have changed in Python 3.6, so OP might have used Python <= 3.5 as well. But the `python2.7` in the directory listing is also a clue ;-)

Comment: @wovano thank you, every day is a school day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.path` contains the paths that Python will search for modules in. You can `append` (or `insert`) to `sys.path` whatever path you need. In your case, the following will add the appropriate path:

```
import sys; sys.path.append('/mnt/local/mahmood/pt/pytorch')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

or

```
pip install package_name -t /path/to/destination
```

Comment: In fact the machine is not connected to the internet. I have built them in the past which has internet connection.